# How do I make the URL of my PHP application consistent on other machines?

Tags: php

I have a PHP application and I gave it to someone to test. Now, that person is writing `http://10.0.2.111/Project/Webpage1.php`and it gets him to the correct page.
Now, when clicks on a link that links to other pages, the URL changes to `http://localhostProject/Webpage2.php` and it doesn't work.

How can I make to URL consistent?

PS: 10.0.2.111 is my machine's IP address.

Comment: Can you show us how you're currently writing your links

Comment: something like this: `if($status=="ok"){ 
echo '<script>window.location.assign("http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php");</script>'; 
}` It checks for validity and then proceeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's happening is your other pc is connecting via an IP address which is great. The code being sent back is using absolute URLs which is obviously broken on the client machine.

What you need to do is either..

### Dynamic URLs

Make use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for example

```
http://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php
```

This allows your code to run under different server names and addresses and will change accordingly

or

### Relative URLs

Instead of specifying the hostname in the URL you can simply use a relative or root relative URL.. for example

```
/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php
```

This has the same affect as the above method but is handled client side, whereas the first method is worked out by the server